# Creating CSS background images dynamically in Rails 3.1 Application Not Linking Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I am trying to dynamically create divs in my Rails app through javascript. However, the divs background images are not linking correctly. I know that Rails will search through images for preloaded css files. For instance, in my main css file I simply have

```
html, body{
 background-image:url('bg.png');
}
```

However, when I create divs dynamically with the following code.

```
        $("<div>").addClass("icon").css("background-image", "url(" + this.model.get('icons')[i] + ")").appendTo(this.el);
```

It doesn't find the images. Do I have to use relative urls such as '/assets/images/...'?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had to set the background image to

```
        $("<div>").addClass("icon").css("background-image", "url('/assets/icon_genes.png')").appendTo(this.el);
```

So apparently, Rails stores all images in just /assets/ as opposed to /assets/images/.

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheets don't work the same way as template files.
You need to put a full path in them for images try:

```
background-image:url('/images/bg.png');
```